# AngularJS + IE8 unknown runtime error

Tags: angularjs, internet-explorer-8

When I tried to click on a link in my home page I am getting following error in IE8

```
Error: Unknown runtime error<div class=ng-scope ng-view ng-1402571375944="5">
```

And the page doesn't loads completely. Please see below picture

[image]

Below is my index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<title>Something</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

<!-- bootstrap -->
<link href="./lib/css/bootstrap/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="./lib/css/bootstrap/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<link href="./lib/css/bootstrap/bootstrap-overrides.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />

<!-- libraries -->
<link href="lib/css/lib/jquery-ui-1.10.2.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="lib/css/lib/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<!--ngGrid Style-->
<link href="lib/css/ng-grid.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>


<!--<link href="lib/css/kalendae.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>-->

<!--daterngepicker css-->
<link href="lib/css/daterangepicker-bs2.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>

<link href="lib/css/nv.d3.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>

<!--link href="lib/css/lib/bootstrap-wysihtml5.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="lib/css/lib/uniform.default.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="lib/css/lib/select2.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"-->
<link href="lib/css/lib/font-awesome.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />

<!-- global styles -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="lib/css/compiled/layout.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="lib/css/compiled/elements.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="lib/css/compiled/icons.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="lib/css/compiled/tables.css">

<!-- open sans font -->
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300italic,400italic,600italic,700italic,800italic,400,300,600,700,800' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

<!-- lato font -->
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300,400,700,900,300italic,400italic,700italic,900italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

<!--[if lt IE 9]>
  <!--script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->

<!--App StyleSheet-->
<link href="lib/css/animate.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">


<!--Google Maps v3 API Script-->
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false"></script>


<!--[if lte IE 8]>
    <script>
      document.createElement('ng-include');
      document.createElement('ng-pluralize');
      document.createElement('ng-view');

      // Optionally these for CSS
      document.createElement('ng:include');
      document.createElement('ng:pluralize');
      document.createElement('ng:view');
    </script>
  <![endif]-->

</head>
<body ng-app="siApp" id="ng-app">


<!-- Angular View -->
<div ng-view></div>

<script src="lib/js/angular.min.js"></script>

<!--Charting Libs-->
<!--<script src="lib/js/d3.min.js"></script>-->
<!--<script src="lib/js/nv.d3.min.js"></script>-->
<script src="lib/js/angularjs-nvd3-directives.min.js"></script>

<!--Scripts -->
<script src="lib/js/jquery-1-10-2.js"></script>
<!--Angular-->



<script src="lib/js/angular-route.min.js"></script>
<script src="lib/js/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
<script src="lib/js/angular-sanitize.min.js"></script>

<!--Google Map Module Dependency-->
<script src="lib/js/underscore-min.js"></script>

<script src="lib/js/json2/json2.js"></script>

<!--Included Modules-->
<script src="lib/js/angular-google-maps.js"></script>
<script src="lib/angular-bootstrap_2.3/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.8.0.js"></script>
<script src="lib/js/ng-grid.js"></script>
<script src="lib/js/moment.min.js"></script>

<!--<script src="lib/js/kalendae.js"></script>
<script src="lib/js/angular.kalendae.js"></script>-->

<!--daterangepicker js-->
 <script src="lib/js/daterangepicker.js"></script>

<script src="lib/js/textAngular.min.js"></script>
<script src="lib/js/textAngular-sanitize.min.js"></script>
<script src="lib/js/ng-infinite-scroll.js"></script>
<script src="lib/js/angular-ng-upload.js"></script>



<!--App JS-->
<script src="js/app.js"></script>

<!--Factories-->
<script src="js/factories/restApp.js"></script>
<script src="js/factories/selectedComponent.js"></script>
<script src="js/factories/selectedAlert.js"></script>
<script src="js/factories/selectedNotification.js"></script>
<script src="js/factories/selectedNewsItem.js"></script>
<script src="js/factories/selectedLink.js"></script>
 <script src="js/factories/selectedHomepageContent.js"></script>
<script src="js/factories/filterui.js"></script>


<!--Services-->
<script src="js/services/instance-data.js"></script>

<!--Directives-->
<script src="js/directives/filter-box.js"></script>
<script src="js/directives/newsfeed.js"></script>
<script src="js/directives/linkfeed.js"></script>


<!--Controllers-->
<script src="js/cntrl/dashboardCtrl.js"></script>
<script src="js/cntrl/infoWindowCtrl.js"></script>
<script src="js/cntrl/alertCtrl.js"></script>

<script src="js/cntrl/alertModalCtrl.js"></script>


<script src="js/cntrl/homeCtrl.js"></script>

<script src="js/cntrl/notificationCtrl.js"></script>
<script src="js/cntrl/notificationModalCtrl.js"></script>

<script src="js/cntrl/adminAlertCtrl.js"></script>
<script src="js/cntrl/adminContentCtrl.js"></script>
<script src="js/cntrl/adminContentNewsTabCtrl.js"></script>
<script src="js/cntrl/adminContentLinkTabCtrl.js"></script>
<script src="js/cntrl/adminContentHomepageTabCtrl.js"></script>
<script src="js/cntrl/newsItemModalCtrl.js"></script>
<script src="js/cntrl/linkModalCtrl.js"></script>
<script src="js/cntrl/homepageModalCtrl.js"></script>

<script src="js/cntrl/profileCtrl.js"></script>
<script src="js/cntrl/adminContentMeasurementTabController.js"></script>
<script src="js/cntrl/adminContentAttachmentsTabCtrl.js"></script>



<!--original theme scripts>
<script src="lib/js/wysihtml5-0.3.0.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script src="lib/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="lib/js/jquery-ui-1.10.2.custom.min.js"></script>
<script src="lib/js/bootstrap-wysihtml5-0.0.2.js"></script>
<script src="lib/js/bootstrap.datepicker.js"></script>
<script src="lib/js/jquery.uniform.min.js"></script>
<script src="lib/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<script src="lib/js/theme.js"></script-->



</body>

</html>
```

What is the problem here? Thanks

Comment: This is just a guess, but is it because there's no `ng-controller` defined?

Comment: Thanks Tom but I don't think defining ng-controller is needed.

Comment: It is working fine in IE9

Comment: which version of angular are you using?

Comment: It is AngularJS v1.2.15

Comment: Have you tried putting quotes around class='ng-scope' ?

Comment: There is no class in my code pls check.. ng-scope is showing in error message, but I didn't defined it

Comment: If we can't reproduce the problem, it's difficult to find a solution. Please, create and **[SSCCE](http://sscce.org)** or a fiddle. (If that is not possible, at least post the rendered HTML (copy-paste from DevTools).

Answer (score 0):

Prepend angular attributes on your index.html page with '`data-`'. IE8 fails sometimes when it meets an unknown attribute. I think there are only two lines that you have to change:

```
...
<body data-ng-app="siApp" id="ng-app">

<!-- Angular View -->
<div data-ng-view></div>
...
```